# What is the best practice to add custom fonts and images in my app in my react-native app (iOS and Android)

Tags: xcode, image, react-native, font-family

I need to know what is the best practice to add fontFamily and images in my react-native app(iOS and Android)

Previously I have used to add the FontFamily and Images in Resources folder of (iOS) and android drawable folder (images)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i've implemented and this is the best solution and description available online. Do check it out.

[Medium RN fonts](https://medium.com/@kswanie21/custom-fonts-in-react-native-tutorial-for-ios-android-76ceeaa0eb78)

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: For the latest react-native version (Link Custom Fonts Manually for Android) is needed or not need. Also I dont have resources folder in my Xcode(App.xcworkspace)

Comment: even if you are using RN>0.60 , i would recommend to link the fonts manually as described in the article in the first two headings like , do follow Link Custom Fonts Manually for iOS and Link Custom Fonts Manually for Android , its very easy. and plus you will get to know a bit more about native code. better for you

Comment: Did you know for image.

Comment: means? i couldnt get it

Comment: How to add image. Your answer is for Fontfamily

Comment: so normally , adding images should be a normal process like create a folder assets and inside it images folder , and then add all PNG or jpeg images of your choice and use it like <Image source={require('../assets/images/image.png')} thats it

Comment: This is okay. But when we go to iOS we need to add the image. Where did you add that image

Comment: like how ive added to adnroid

Comment: I have created a new folder Fonts under my target and tried. But it not works. So I moved out from the folder for iOS it woks. But it looks bad. So many files ar there

Comment: have you tried using fractal folder structure to keep everything in place?

Comment: Now I can able to see the resources folder after creacting the assests folder

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have added custom font as mentioned in this blog. And It is working fine.

https://medium.com/@sharadkatre01/custom-font-installation-in-react-native-e8ac44b7a121

Comment: Is it work good for iOS and Android? This is a best practice or not?

Comment: I think it only works for android. Also react-native link works upto the version RN<0.59. Then how it will works. Where need to create assest folder under iOS or Android

Comment: Yes, It is for the higher version of the RN<0.59. I will update you for Lower Version.

Comment: Then the way above mentioned has no problem. It works on both iOS and Android.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203590/discussion-between-sharad-s-katre-and-sejn).